# Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms, catch-all

*This is a general, community wiki [catch-all](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/685/proposed-catch-all-i-need-a-content-management-system-that-will-do-x-y-and-z) question to address non-specific "I need a CMS or Wiki that does x, y, and z..." questions.*

*If your question was closed as a duplicate of this question and you feel that the information provided here does not provide a sufficient answer, please open a discussion on [Webmasters Meta](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/).*

---

I have a list of features that I want for my website's Content Management System (CMS) - where can I find a [free] script that includes all of them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Webmasters FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) outlines the nature of acceptable questions for this site: researching available solutions and providing anecdotal advice falls outside the purpose of this StackExchange site, so this type of question would be better-suited to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) or another discussion forum.

That being said, there are a variety of free and open source content management systems, as well as licensed software and paid services, which may meet your requirements.

Some of the most popular content management systems include:

- [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) (PHP, free and open source) – a blogging platform which has expanded to include many other features – See the [wordpress stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) if you have any questions.
- [Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/) (PHP, free and open source)
- [Drupal](https://drupal.org/) (PHP, free and open source) – See the [drupal stackexchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) if you have any questions.
- [DotNetNuke](https://www.dotnetnuke.com/) (ASP, proprietary or free and open source option)
- [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) (PHP, free and open source) – the software that powers Wikipedia
- [Umbraco](https://umbraco.com) (MVC.NET, open source)
- [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) (PHP, free and open source) – a simple but powerful wiki software
- [Typo3](https://typo3.org/) (PHP, Open Source (GPL)) - powerful for medium and large projects

All of the content management systems listed above are built around the concept of [plug-ins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29) which extend the application's functionality—there are many plug-ins, with new plug-ins authored every day.

Sites like [The CMS Matrix](http://cmsmatrix.org/) and [WikiMatrix](https://www.wikimatrix.org/search.php) can help you compare CMS's (but is best suited for looking for very particular combinations of requirements).

If you have researched content management systems and available plug-ins but cannot find anything that will meet your needs, you should consult a developer who can build something to your specifications either as a plug-in for an existing content management system or as a stand-alone application.

Comment: You should add [ProcessWire](https://processwire.com/)  to the list, a very scalable, user-friendly CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one paragraph if you are indecisive about what CMS to use..

Today every CMS is "easy" to use from the client's side. Most users are using CMS to post articles or publish galleries because you want to have them to modify their content. You just need to prepare territory for them.

Majority of users are using Wordpress. Some statistics show that 51% of all web pages are using Wordpress as their CMS. So basically, logical weapon of for creating something is wordpress. (As for statistic concerned)

There's great graph here on this link so you can get the wider picture, I'll just print screen one, and put link to the site

[image]

**SOURCE:** http://trends.builtwith.com/cms