# What free website system do you recommend to promote intepretation/translation services

Tags: advertising, marketing, open-source, template

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I am a business interpreter based in Hangzhou,China. I am considering to mount an independent website to promote my service. I will register a domain name for it. My question is, what free website system do you recommend? The website system needs to include a content management system so I can add information.

Comment: You should find this answer helpful http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use/25746#25746

Answer (score 1):

Worpdress.com is easy enough for beginners and has very interesting features for advanced users.