# Which eCommerce has a good module with product configurator?

Tags: ecommerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

i'm looking for a eCommerce software which have also a good "product configurator". My company sells product highly configurable. Which ecommerce has a good configurator ?
Thanks

Comment: Please see this answer http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use

Answer (score 0):

CS-Cart has a good product configurator. http://www.cs-cart.com/