# Could any current, well supported CMS support a live action role playing game?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms, webserver, wiki

A group of friends and I are looking to create a system which will support and allow interactions between a group of up to 70 people using mobile devices (phones and tablets) as part of a science fiction themed [freeform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeform_role-playing_game) game.

In order to minimize development effort and support as wide a range of devices as possible, it's become clear that a web server based infrastructure is the only practical solution.  The server would be connected to a wireless network, and the players would use their web browsers to access the server wirelessly.  I think the only thing that will do the job is some sort of CMS, but I have no detailed experience with any CMS and as such could do with some advice as to suitable platforms.

**Required functionality** is:

1. Some sort of wiki containing game information.
2. The ability for both players and referees to be able to identify themselves to the system by log in.
3. Access control to a per user and per page granularity (not all users will have access to the same pieces of information)
4. (Text based) messaging (essentially email) from within the web interface
5. A notebook page for each player to make their own notes.

**Required user interface features** are:

1. A UI optimised for mobile and touch devices
2. The ability to increase the text size of the interface for each device
3. Not too complex to use - some of our end users will not be technically minded

The **required infrastructure** is:

1. Extensibility without a huge learning curve - we have several people with a programming and/or systems administration background, but this is a hobby project for all of us, and none of us are CMS or web app gurus.  In particular we are likely to need to develop a script to change users access permissions if they scan a QR code at some point in the game (giving them access to new information).
2. Longevity - this system is likely to be in use for at least 5 years (in short bursts, but not being able to maintain or set up a new server in 3 years time would be a real problem).

Things which are **desirable**, but are not essential

1. Some sort of off-line operation (don't think we're going to get this one, but it doesn't hurt to ask)
2. Built in voice/video conferencing/messaging
3. Ability to tie a log-in to a device so the user only has to log-in once (mobile web browsers often being killed by the OS task manager the moment the user switches to something else)
4. Something that looks good on a tablet as well as a phone screen

What sort of solutions would people suggest if they needed to develop a system with these requirements?

Comment: Would those closing this question be so good as to point me at the other question that answers is.  I certainly can't find it.

Comment: I would vote to reopen if I could, but it looks as though questions about which CMS systems support which are generally redirected to [this catch all question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use). It seems rather cheap to close it as an exact duplicate and not leave a link to the question that it is an exact of! If it is a policy decision not to allow this type of question then they should be closed as Too Localised and a note should be added to the FAQ to remind people of this.

Comment: See also the [meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/) questions [New Catch-All: “Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?”](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/685/13697) and [We need to decide what we're doing with users looking for existing software](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/597/13697).

Comment: One vote was to close as *too localised*, see the comments on my answer [on meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/718/13697).

Comment: I'm aware of a sourceforge project for an [RPG-CMS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openrpg-cms/) but it looks like it was last updated in 2009, but I guess you could get involved with the project and reopen it. There is also [Suite GM](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Ys5zGb1n2WYJ:plone.org/support/sites/suite-gm-role-playing-gaming-computer-utility-aide-software-development+roleplaying+game+cms&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) for [Plone](plone.org) which was designed with this kind of use in mind. [RP-Tools](http://rptools.net/) may also be worth a look.

Comment: I suspect that you may end up extending another CMS in which case take a close look at Drupal - it's much easier for developers to extend than others and you should be able to find modules for messaging and permissions quite easily.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles Thanks for the helpful suggestions.  Most of these relate to tabletop RPGs which have quite different needs, but I think you may be right about Drupal + modules being the likely best bet.

Comment: @Christi yeah I realize they are not quite what you're looking for but hopefully the might lead you to the right people. I suspect you will have to write something yourself.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745). I am unsure why it isn't showing automatically, though.

Comment: @John Conde That is not what is normally meant by the term "exact duplicate" in conventional English usage.  I think su's alternative basis of "too localised" makes the difficulty with this question clearer.  As Mark Booth says, it's disappointing that this restriction isn't made clear in the FAQ as it took me considerable time to write this question that I could have avoided wasting if it had been mentioned there.  Thank you for providing the link though.

Comment: @JohnConde - Agreed, closing as *Too localised* and providing a link to the [catch-all](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use) answer would have been better, but I'm sure we all appreciate that moderators have a lot to do and sometimes these things slip through the net.