# PHP photo/album gallery script with an admin backend and easy to integrate

Tags: web-development, looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm looking for an open source photo and album gallery software that should be is easy to integrate in a webpage and have an easy-to use back , admin panel for adding/deleting/modifying photo/albums and thumb resizer . I've found myGallery which basically does what I want but it doesn't cache photos and is **really** slow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the following?

http://gallery.menalto.com/