# Whether to use Joomla or NOT for a site with following specifications?

Tags: joomla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I want **Joomla developers** perspective for: "**Whether its advisable or not to use Joomla**" if I wish to develop a site with following features:
1. Mainly focused in e-learning. (quite similar to http://grockit.com)
2. Registered **students** can:
watch/download videos/slides present on the site,
-give quiz (either solo or multi-player) on various predefined topics on the portal,
-when chosen multi-player, they can chat with the other currently on the same quiz,
-get a complete explanation of all questions after attempting the quiz,
-see his/her profile/status on the portal.
3. **Teachers** can:
can upload questions/slides/videos on the site(through a UI),
review questions uploaded by some other teacher,
can join a chat-room(quiz) and help students solve the quiz.
4. **Admin**(not necessarily a website developer) can:
-approve new teachers requests.
-manage contents of the website(through a UI).

The key points are:
The site won't ultimately be handled by the developers. The future admin may not know any programming at all!
Is the compatibility issue on various versions of Joomla a big problem?
Is it really easy for person with no programming skills to handle the site afterwards?
Is Joomla efficient enough and easy to learn for developers?
Are there sufficient number of Joomla extensions/plugins available for developing such a portal. And whether its easy to edit/modify those plugins?

What we are capable of developing:

1. All the basic features including personal/group chat,video streaming,and the required coding for development of the UI for students and teachers.
2. Also we presently do not have any time constraints for the development of this portal.

Comment: i m more specific :D

Comment: Generally speaking we don't do content management system reccomendations, hence the generic answer. Basically it's not a good fit for the Q&A format and any modern open source CMS can do the things you want - which one is best for your project is a wholly subjective question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Joomdle - which is Joomla integrated with Moodle (a learning management system) http://www.joomdle.com/en/. By adding the Moodle integration you'll have far more robust tools for things like tests, assignment submissions and most importantly - grading.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles: can u be more specific please??? I need a specific answer.

Comment: and plz unmark this question as closed

Comment: @r20rock this is a Q&A site, if you need advice on Joomla then the Joomla forums would be a better place to ask your question. You're looking for a reccomendation not an answer.