# Blogging platform that supports group , private , public blogs and advanced tagging

Tags: blog, community-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

After some bad questions here, i finally have my main question in mind :)

I need to design a platform that provides:

-Personal blogging (blogs that are view able only by them)
-Group blogging (blogs that only people part of a small group (3-4 people) can see the posts and comment)
-Public blogs

Also about the content itself, i would need

-Advanced tagging (common tags amongst all blogs AND tags specific to a blog in addition to the common)
-Search capability
-Rich text content with photos media e.tc. on the blog entry
-A database that i could access and create custom applications (most read-only) on the data. Also an API would be helpfull.

an example of a custom application would be to select your blog posts and create an offline file (.zip html e.t.c) and have it stored locally on your machine.

After some research:

-Forum platforms are NOT suitable for this as i would have to create hundreds of sub forums with selective security for each of them. It would make administration almost if not impossible.

-Joomla and joomla-alike cms also give me bad signs as i couldn't have specialized tags per category of articles and i suspect heavy coding in order to do it. Also i don't know if it could satisfy my other above-mentioned needs.

-I have found a combo that may work. Invision Board and IP.Blog. IP.blog supports almost all of the features that i want ,but it seems maybe too good to be true (any input of someone that already uses it would be helpful).

Many solutions follow the logic that a blog is public and allow for some level of security on them, which is not suitable for what i want.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a good fit for the Q/A format, any answer provided will be subjective, you'd be better asking this on forum based sites as it's opinion you're looking for.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles: i think its not a dup cause i am not looking for a CMS , its kinda custom requirement ...

Comment: Also i know it could be better of in a forum, but i trust you guys here :)

Comment: From the requirements you've specified you're looking for a wiki with a blogging platform built in. But in general we don't do reccomendation questions.

Comment: Our policy is to have some general questions that we close any recommendation questions as duplicates of. You might want to go somewhere else to ask this question, like a forum.