# I want something ready to start with

Tags: website-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I am looking for something quick like a weblog in wordpress or blogspot maybe, that when I write a blog post I can put it there, for example if I write something about .NET or Java or Database,..some quick tutorial with some small code samples that visitors can use ...
And I don't know anything about webdesign and I just want a ready-made thing to use for this purpose. What do you suggest? any samples of that that I can take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't go down the route of Google docs and sharing the link because, as far as I know, they are not indexed. People won't be finding your posts in search engines.

I would go with wordpress.com as its free, hosted and there are tons of free themes.

Comment: yep, I registered something in Wordpress.org, they had some hosting that had a one-click install kind of thing for wordpress blogs.

Answer (score 2):

[Blogger](http://www.blogger.com/home?pli=1) seems like it would be good for your purposes.  It's free and a very quick set up for blogging.

If you're looking for something a little more tweakable, try [SquareSpace](http://www.squarespace.com/).  It cost money though, but you get a free trial.

If you plan on writing about .NET, BlogEngine.NET (http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) might be worth a try - but you may have to host it somewhere on your own.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of folks are using wordpress for just that, thought I prefer blogger or even a g+ account. The best I can think of would be a G+ account and use google docs (docs.google.com) to write your "blog" and simply share that document on G+ think of it like writing tutorials in chapter in a book. I hope that helps G+/GDocs would require the least amount of setup.