# Any CMS or Framework that support MongoDB as the only database?

Tags: cms, mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'd like to exercise mongodb in a real world context so I'm wondering what are CMS', or better, Frameworks that support MongoDB as the main database out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lithium](http://lithify.me/) (a PHP Frameword) supports Mongo out-of-the-box. And you will find [plenty others](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Libraries,+Frameworks,+and+Tools#PHPLibraries,Frameworks,andTools-LibrariesandFrameworks) from the mongoDB website. Do not forget to check the right menu, ton of things to read in the *Drivers* submenu.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Locomotive: http://locomotivecms.com, and have been fairly impressed so far. Uses Ruby on Rails, Mongoid, MongoDB, all default.

Answer (score 1):

**MongoPress - The High-Performance, Object-Based, PHP, MongoDB CMS**

I would try http://www.mongopress.org/