# Which wikis have MarkDown support?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, wiki, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

There exist a [MarkDown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) extension for MediaWiki, but it is very [buggy](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MarkdownSyntax).

Does anyone know of wikis that support MarkDown?

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Go to http://www.wikimatrix.org/search.php.
- Choose `Markdown Support` under `Syntax Features` from the list on the left.
- Click Search.

I get 28 results.

Comment: For those who can't decide which one to use, choose the one with the last updated date.