# What is a good solution for web based course management portal?

Tags: website-design, cms, web-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I am looking to host a web based course portal in my college. The portal would be used for the following tasks:

- Instructors will upload lecture notes, assignments, embed videos(youtube etc.)
- Students will consume the content, and in addition upload their assignment submissions.
- Instructors and TAs will monitor students progress and give feedback.
- Students, instructors and TA's will use a forum on the portal for discussions.

Could you please recommend a good web based solution(preferably free) which would satisfy the aforementioned requirements to the most.

Comment: Moodle is commonly used for this sort of thing.

Comment: I am disappointed with the closing of a sufficiently broad question under a crazy broad catch-all question. I am pretty sure a lot of people like me are looking for a CMS with similar requirements. For people like me, a good answer to this would save a lot of time spent digging through tens of CMS's and trying them out to see which works best.