# News Portal CMS

Tags: cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use)

I am looking for a specific news portal CMS. I know all the major "general" CMS (like WordPress, Drupal or Joomla) and even the less known ones (like TYPO3, Expression Engine, Text Pattern or Concrete5). I'm already working with a Drupal distribution called OpenPublish and another WordPress installation to determine which would be better, but these are more of a Plan B.

I would like to work directly with a CMS that was build exactly for this kind of tasks specific to a news / media portal. It doesn't matter if the CMS is commercial (however, I don't want to pay a monthly fee) or free, but I need to be able to use it on my own server / hosting and I need to be able to access it's source code (not to modify it, but to integrate it with future plugins / modules).

If you know any CMS that qualifies for this job, please let me know. In the last few days I was all over Google but I couldn't anything worth mentioning.