# php cms withouth database

Tags: php, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use)

A friend of mine asked me for a easy website for him. As it was just 3 subpages, no database need or anything, I've done it quite fast with plain PHP, HTML, JS and CSS. But then another and another friend showed up. They only wanted arrange differently they navigation, some different picutures etc.

So I though, is there any kind of CMS, that allows build small business website (barbershop, local groceries shop), with small list of subpages, yet allowing us to arrange look'n'feel. There's no need for the databas as content won't change, or can be stored in simple textfiles for example.

Things like WordPress might be simple overkill

Does anyone know such cms?

Comment: Well, I think John Conde didn't understand the user's idea. He wanted a cms that is able to operate without database and YES there is a way to do that: KURE. Please see here: https://github.com/skoh-fley/kure You can download the package and give it a try.