# Which CMS or framework for a website with classified ads?

Tags: wordpress, cms, ecommerce, joomla, advertising

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use)

A non-technical friend has asked me to provide some guidance for his new website idea.
To avoid losing a friend - I intend to send him to another professional to setup and maintain his website.

The idea is not revolutionary - a basic website with user submitted ads, but given it is for a niche he might get some traction and I wish him good luck with that.

Given that functionality is really very standard, should I suggest to him that he goes with something fairly mainstream such as Joomla or Wordpress that can be easily hosted on shared hosting?

The only data that we want secure is the emails and phone numbers of the ad submitters. Any particular steps to take there?

The other major req is that the site works well on mobile devices.
Which particular product would you suggest and why?

I also welcome any general suggestions on products or approaches that he can take.

Answer (score 1):

Appthemes sells a theme for wordpress called [Classipress](http://www.appthemes.com/themes/classipress/).  I have not used this but it appears to be a good solution for ads.  I do plan in the future to test this but be advised it is **not** free.

Comment: I have used Appthemes for a number of my sites including their jobs board for www.digitalcareersearch.com

Comment: @JackLockyer how well was the back end code and admin panel structured?  Would you refer people to use it?

Comment: why is this thread closed when it has not relation to the post you're pointing to?  The OP clearly asked for a "Classified" solution and an answer was provided.  Your link clearly shows a general concept of a CMS.  This post first mentioned a solution for classified but was edited by j0k and now its closed by another member.