# Choosing a CMS for Non-Technical Users

Tags: cms, wysiwyg, dreamweaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use)

I am currently looking for a free CMS geared towards non-technical users.  I'm hoping to find something where they can easily create tables, move blocks around, with a WYSIWYG editor, etc.  Does such a thing exist?

Myself, I can put up with any CMS I come across.  I can use HTML/CSS/PHP/MySQL/etc., so I can install whatever I need to and add edits wherever I need to for the web design/template/theme.

I know the popular ones: WordPress, Drupal, and Joomla.  They're apparently not simple enough for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

A bit surprised that the popular Wordpress seemed not simple enough, but maybe you should have a look at [opensourcecms.com](http://www.opensourcecms.com/) as they have tons of CMS for you to try as a demo.

You may also have a look at [EZ-Publish](http://ez.no/Community)