# Looking for a Social Bookmarking Content Management System

Tags: cms, social-media, looking-for-similar

I want to make a website like Reddit, I already tried Pligg, Drigg, Elgg but the codes were too messy and impossible to customize.

I really like WordPress and Joomla but they are not designed for that, I am wondering any suggestion or plugin to make them like Reddit or other cms?

Comment: Please read: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reddit is a social book mark site as you know so here is a list of potential social book marks, I have included the ones you have used for the experience of others with similar questions.

- [Dotnetkicks](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetkicks/downloads/list) ([Demo](http://www.dotnetkicks.com/))
- [Grab the Mic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grabthemic/)
- [Baker CMS](http://bakercms.com/)
- [Kubelabs PHPDug](http://www.kubelabs.com/phpdug/)
- [Shuttle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scuttle/)
- [Slashcode](http://slashcode.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=slashcode/slashcode;a=tree;h=refs/heads/live;hb=live)
- [The Peoples Feed](http://github.com/jenglert/The-Peoples--Feed)
- [Scoop](http://www.scoopdev.org/)
- [Pligg](http://pligg.com/)
- [Drigg](http://drupal.org/project/drigg)
- [Elgg](http://elgg.org/)

Turning WordPress into a Social Bookmarking Site

You can use the following plugins and make your own social bookmarking site in WordPress, it might be worth check the extension library as their is many more which will do similar.

- [Buddylinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-links/)
- [Vote it up](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/)