# What CMS is used for this site?

Tags: cms

Would love to know the specifics if anyone can 'see' which cms this site (bite squad dot com) uses?

A off the shelf solution?  Did they integrate various CMS ?

Would love to know!   Thanks

Comment: This question is about a website that is not your own.

Comment: We also don't accept questions about CMS or Wiki recommendations.   We have a single question with general advice about choosing a content management system: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use

Answer (score 2):

Well, as http://whatcmsisthis.com/ doesn't recognise it, and the log-in area appears to be created with https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle (very few CMSs don't have user management out-of-the-box), then I would be pretty sure that it is a bespoke system using various bits of third party code and apis to achieve its means.

It also uses mapQuest and snapengage.

Some of the code also makes me suspect it is using the Symfony framework.